# source based install of orocos_kinematics_dynamic failed with vcs not setup correctly when installing ros electric from source

Tags: ros, archlinux, rosinstall, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the following:

```
rosinstall ~/ros-electric/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"
```

And got this at the very end of the output:

```
Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/kdlclone orocos_kinematics_dynamics-0.2.1 to /home/ajc/ros-electric/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
Cloning into /home/ajc/ros-electric/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics...
remote: Counting objects: 2292, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (893/893), done.
remote: Total 2292 (delta 1502), reused 2092 (delta 1363)
Receiving objects: 100% (2292/2292), 668.20 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1502/1502), done.
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point is not a branch.
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/home/ajc/ros-electric/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics'
 vcs not setup correctly
```

I realize I'm installing to ~/ros-electric/ros. I tried installing to ~/ros and the same problem emerges.

I have seen http://answers.ros.org/question/1645/vcs-not-setup-correctly-while-i-install-ros-using, and have attempted the installation about 10 times, always receiving this output.

I can and have installed diamondback with no issues. (I have removed its previous installation at ~/ros (its the only directory I removed, the problem still persists) I also tried removing the ~/.ros directory.

Some information:

```
git version 1.7.6
rosinstall 0.5.15
Linux whales 2.6.39-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jul 9 15:31:04 CEST 2011 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual-Core Processor TK-55 AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10828/source-based-install-of-orocos_kinematics_dynamic-failed-with-vcs-not-setup-correctly-when-installing-ros-electric-from-source/) by [ajc](https://answers.ros.org/users/931/ajc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that this was an issue with the repository from which it was checkout out orocos_kinematics_dynamics.  That's what the error means, and I've just tried the command myself now and it works.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1